# Dynamic Attribute using Angular (Not input/require)

Tags: angularjs

I need to contruct the following

```
<button large></button>
<button larger></button>
```

I would like to do something like...

```
<!-- where items = ["large", "larger"] -->

<button ng-repeat="item in items" {{item.type}}>Whatever</button>
```

How would I go about this? I tried the above but it didn't seem to work

I would expect...

```
<button large class="ng-binding">Whatever</button>
<button larger class="ng-binding">Whatever</button>
```

but I get

```
<button {{item.type}} class="ng-binding">Whatever</button>
<button {{item.type}} class="ng-binding">Whatever</button>
```

As you can see the button fails to have the appropriate attr.

Comment: You cannot really do this directly with bindings, after all this is a super weird requirement :). There are even places where you can dynamically set attribute values using `ng-attr` (ng-attr-custtype="{{item.type}}" will set `custtype="large" etc`) or You could even set `ng-class`. What are you achieving by doing `<button large` etc..? sorry this makes no sense to me... If you really want you would need to create a directive which sets attribute on the element

Comment: Yeah it is weird and essentially due to the library I was trying to use so I ended up rewriting the library that way but the question remains the Same. Another example I can think of is porting weird jQuery libs